# Extend trait from another module

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.2, multi-module

I have a project including three modules.

- main
- domain
- infrastructure

In domain module I have a entity class and a repository trait.

`Entity.scala`
`EntityRepository`

In infrastructure module I want to extend and implement the EntityRepository trait.

```
EntityRepositoryImpl extends EntityRepository {...}
```

But I don't know how to access the trait in the domain mobdule from the infrastructure module.

I'm not sure that I know what I'm doing but here by build.sbt. Tell me if I've done something wrong there.

```
import play.Project._

lazy val domain = Project("domain", file("domain"))

lazy val infra = Project("infrastructure", file("infrastructure")).dependsOn(domain)

lazy val root = Project("MainModuleName", file(".")).dependsOn(domain, infra)

name := "AppName"

version := "1.0"

playScalaSettings
```

---

Now suddenly I can find the EntityRepository in the EntityRepositoryImpl but when I choose to extend it it's still red and showing a 'Cannot resolve...'-error.

[image: Finds the trait]

[image: Still red if I choose it]

Happy for any kind of feedback!
Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error from compiler in IntelliJ or when you run "sbt compile"
?

Comment: @RadoBuransky no error from compiler. Well if I add the "extends EntityRepository" it fails, because EntityRepository cannot be found. I mean, I cannot import that trait in the EntityRepositoryImpl class.

Comment: That's what I am asking about. Whether the error message comes from IntelliJ or SBT. It may be that IntelliJ project is not up-to-date. Run "sbt gen-idea" (if you're using that plugin) to regenerate IntelliJ project from build.sbt.

Answer (score 1):

Your project setup allows you to access `EntityRepository` trait which is in `domain` subproject from anywhere in `infra` subproject because `infra` depends on `domain`. All you need to do is to reference `EntityRepository` by its full name or import the package where it resides (`import com.example.EntityRepository`).

If you use IntelliJ you can generate projects for it from sbt using `sbt-idea` plugin. The same goes for Eclipse with `sbteclipse-plugin`. This way your generated IDE projects would have proper references to each other and will help you find your classes.

Although you have the same package in two different SBT subprojects it's not a problem. This should not cause any compilation problems.

To eliminate problems that could be caused by IDE a good test is to compile with SBT. Shutdown running sbt, start it over again and run `;clean; compile; test` in SBT console. If everything compiles fine (or even if it does not) regenerate your IntelliJ projects with `gen-idea` from SBT console. For all SBT commands in your case you should be in `root` project which I suppose is default location when you start SBT.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Aleksey.
What do you mean with "you can generate projects for it using sbt using sbt-idea plugin" ? 

The project is idealized with play idea but the thing is that I cannot use the EntityRepository in the infra-module. It's all red and won't give me any import suggestions. 
When I try to import the module nothing is found. 

But what I've done should work then?

Comment: Edited my post with some images

Comment: the best test is to write that piece of code anyway even if it does not compile with IntelliJ and then in sbt shell run `;clean; compile` and see if it compiles. Don't forget to reload sbt if you make any SBT related changes. You might also have to regenerate your IntelliJ projects from sbt if you use the `sbt-idea` plugin with `;gen-idea`. Please let us know if sbt is able to compile all projects.